# Oracle Sql - Script suns extremely slow when include a subquery in a IN statement

Tags: sql, oracle

Table: Number

```
A     B
----- --
12    34
22    34
11    35
13    36
```

Table: Data

```
B     C     D
----- ----- --
34    A     B
34    C     D
35    E     F
35    G     H
36    I     J
36    K     L
```

I want to return value in B when A is a duplicate mapping to B. In the example, 34 is selected(in practice, it will return over 100+ duplicate values).

After getting 34, I want to return all rows in 'Data' table where B=34

```
B     C     D
----- ----- -----
34    A     B
34    C     D
```

My Try:

```
With Number as (
    select  B,count(B) as count
    from  Number
    where 1=1
    group by B
)
, Number2 As (
    select B
    from Number 
    where count>1
, Data As (
    select * from Data where B in (select * from Number2)
)
```

But when I run the script, it runs extremely slow. I am wondering if there is any better way to make it faster

Answer (score 1):

How about JOIN? Lines #1 - 15 represent sample data (you don't type that); query you do need begins at line #16.

```
SQL> with
  2  tnumber (a, b) as
  3    (select 12, 34 from dual union all
  4     select 22, 34 from dual union all
  5     select 11, 35 from dual union all
  6     select 13, 36 from dual
  7    ),
  8  tdata (b, c, d) as
  9    (select 34, 'a', 'b' from dual union all
 10     select 34, 'c', 'd' from dual union all
 11     select 35, 'e', 'f' from dual union all
 12     select 35, 'g', 'h' from dual union all
 13     select 36, 'i', 'j' from dual union all
 14     select 36, 'k', 'l' from dual
 15    )
 16  select d.*
 17  from tdata d join (select n.b
 18                     from tnumber n
 19                     group by n.b
 20                     having count(*) > 1
 21                    ) x
 22                 on d.b = x.b;

         B C D
---------- - -
        34 a b
        34 c d

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause as follows:

```
SELECT *
  FROM DATA_TABLE D
 WHERE D.B IN (
    SELECT B
      FROM NUMBER_TABLE
     GROUP BY B
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1)
```

Index on column B in both the table will help you reducing the query cost.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try:

```
SELECT D.* FROM(SELECT B FROM Number GROUP BY B HAVING COUNT(B) > 1)TEMP
JOIN DATA D ON D.B = TEMP.B
```